# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS ::: Unity ::: Dash Issues ::: Missing Programmes

Tags: 20.04, unity-dash, lts

I've just updated to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Unity is my desktop of choice.

In short, lots of programmes seem to be missing, including Thunderbird, Telegram, Terminal [odd] and the Software Centre, which is very odd.

If I log into the Gnome Ubuntu all is well, except Gnome is awful.
In short, how do get back Thunderbird and the rest when I don't have Terminal or the Software Centre ? I've tried opening them in Gnome, then back out, into Unity, thinking that may, somehow, make Ubuntu "remember" they exist, but they are still not accessible.

*Update : I have created a new user, logged into Gnome and all is well. Log back into Unity [as the new user or the original] and the programmes are still missing.

It /feels/ like the programmes are there, as Gnome / XFCE can both see / use them [Thunderbird / Telegram etc] but Unity / Dash simply does not see them. It is as if the log files that Dash would use to know what is on the hard drive have been deleted and Dash will not / has not "re-scanned" and indexed. Is this how Dash works; Ich weiss est nicht.....

** Update Two : the issue is 100% with the Dash. If I create a keyboard short cut [ctrl + m for example] for email, then Thunderbird will open. Therefore the issue is with the Dash in Unity not working CORRECTLY post 20.04 LTS upgrade.

**Thoughts, because I am stumped.**

Thanks.
P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have it resolved.
Essentially, I have re-installed Unity.

```
sudo apt update.

sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop --install-suggests
```

Following @Eirik advice of thinking about it differently...

Dash was working, except it didn't seem to know what what was installed on the HD. Nothing wrong with Unity. SO it seemed to be some db issue. So, if I re-install Unity that should also [re]build the db at the same time. 30 mins later I have a fully working 20.04 LTS with a working Dash.

Oh and @Eirik I hate Gnome. I'm going to have a proper look at UbuntyUnity.org and may run that on a separate machine and see how that works out.....
Cheerio.
P.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access a terminal with Ctrl + Alt + F3. Then log in with your username and password. TTY I think it's called. It is full screen so, I would recommend to install a terminal immediately so you don't have to stay there for everything.

```
sudo apt install gnome-terminal
```

Ctrl + Alt + F2 should put you back in unity. If not, try the other F#'s

It used to be the other F#'s on ubuntu, not sure if this is a Gnome thing or ubuntu 20.04

Hope it works.

Comment: This helped, and it didn't. Ctrl + Alt + F3 did bring up the TTY. When I tried to install Terminal it told me Terminal is already installed. Thunderbird the same.

When I use the Dash to find / open programmes Dash says "nothing available". It /feels/ like the programmes are there, but are not "visible" to the Dash. If I log into Gnome, there are no issues [other than Gnome being awful] this is a Unity only issue. 

Any further help would be useful.
P.

Comment: This sounds familiar. I think maybe this happened to me once i tried to install unity on linux mint. I was not able to resolve the issue, but maybe we can attack this from a different angle.

Is there any reason to keep gnome? it seems like you are not the biggest fan :)

I also ran into whole lot's of other unrelated problems back in the day with installing unity alongside gnome. Some software was doubling up and such. so I decided to install from the mini.iso instead, and just install barebones before installing unity on its own. maybe this is something you could do?

Comment: Here are instructions to install only unity with the mini.iso : (I recommend to also to add uefi to the .iso) -

https://codepre.com/how-to-use-mini-iso-to-perform-a-clean-ubuntu-20-04-or-18-04-installation-via-unity.html

Comment: Also, there is this: https://ubuntuunity.org/